# AVD rotates 90 degrees but the screen orientation does nothing

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

Ok,  I have tried using ctrl f12, ctrl f11, 7, and 9.  They all do the exact same thing.  They rotate the screen and then I wait 30 minutes and the content on the avd does not rotate with the avd.  It is like I have it locked,  but as you can see that is not the issue in my code.  This is to a very basic code that just has text on the screen.  Nothing more.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.lineware.scheduler"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="org.lineware.scheduler.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: By setting the `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` attribute you are telling that you will handle the screen size and orientation changes by your own. Are you handling it properly on the `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)` of your `org.lineware.scheduler.MainActivity`?

Comment: What android version are you running on your AVD?

Comment: @tato.rodrigo I added that because of the problem.  I am using the latest one.  I cant find it,  but I downloaded it today.  So I know it is the latest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my answer based on your comment:

If you are using the latest Android AVD then you are using 4.4 (KitKat). The KitKat AVD is known to have problems with rotation (as in: it stays in portrait mode even though the emulator turned 90 degrees).

This is a known problem reported by a lot of people and I have faced this problem myself as well (see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61671).

I fixed it by getting the 4.3 SDK and creating an AVD with Android version 4.3 (JellyBean) which does not have this bug.

Comment: Awesome,  I will further investigate.  Thanks for this bit of info.

Comment: Did you try what I suggested? Did it help you?